# Limit of the average of the product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Suppose we have two non-negative sequences: $a_n$ and $b_n$. Specifically, we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}{N}=a$$
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} b_N=b$$

Do we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n}{N}=ab ?$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The answer to this question is yes.

Comment: The way to see this intuitively is that when $b_n$ is young, it may sow its wild oats all over the place. But the fact that it has a limit says at some point $b_n$ become positively stodgy, just repeating practically the same value over and over again. And as $N$ gets large enough, it dwarfs all the contributions of those wild early days, so the stodginess is all that really matters.